# How can I Implement an average of integers stored in a given stack using C? I have the main and average code but I Can't combine them with each other

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, stack

This is a question in the DSA course.

This is the main code.

````
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

int stack[SIZE], t;

void stack_init(void);
void pop(void);
int top(void);
int empty(void);
int push(int x);

int main() {
  int i;
  int loop = 1;
  stack_init();
  while (loop == 1) {
    scanf("%d", & i);
    if (i == 0) {
      if (empty())
        printf("Error - Stack is empty\n");
      else
        pop();
    } else if (i < 0) {
      if (empty())
        printf("Error - Stack is empty\n");
      else
        printf("%d\n", top());
    } else
      if(push(i)==0)
      {
          printf("Stack is full\n");
      }
  }
}


//****************************************************
// Implement the calcualte average here

//****************************************************


//function to check the array is full
int is_full()
{
    //if T is equal to size 
    if(t==SIZE-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void stack_init(void) {
  t = -1;
}

//variation of push which returns true and false
int push(int x)
{
    //if array is full
    if(is_full())
        return 0;
    //otherwise push the element
    t = t + 1;
    stack[t] = x;
    //return success
    return 1;
}


void pop(void) {
  t = t - 1;
}

int top(void) {
  return stack[t];
}

int empty(void) {
  return t == -1;
}```
````

What I want is calculate the average of integers stored in a given stack.
the stack must be in its original form. I can use temporary data structures during the operation.

And this is the average code that I want to Implement.

```
double average;

CreateStack(&stack);

while (!StackFull(&stack)) {
Push(val, &stack); }// push value on to stack


while (!StackEmpty(&stack)) {
average += Pop(&stack); } // pop value from stack
average = average / StackFull(&stack); // calculate average


while (!StackEmpty(&stack)) {
Push(Pop(&stack), &stack);} // put values back on stack


return average;
```

Please help to to find the answer of this question.

Comment: An average would generally require the usage of a floating-point accumulator (i.e., either `float` or `double`, neither of which appears anywhere in your code).

Comment: Ok, np to this. but the question now is how to do it :) how can I Implement it there.

Comment: And the second time you do `while (!StackEmpty(&stack))` is obviously meaningless, because the stack is already empty by the end of the first time.

Comment: Do you mean the  // pop value from stack one, or the // put values back on stack. ? which one ?

Comment: The first thing you should have learnt is the difference between `c` and `c#`.  Why the latter tag?

Comment: I see two occurrences of `while (!StackEmpty(&stack))` at the end of your question. The second one seems meaningless.

Comment: The key is that you can use temporary data structures. So, what you do is pop elements of the stack and push onto a temporary stack. Along the way, you accumulate the total sum of these (and remember to initialize `average` to 0, since your current example has it uninitialized). Now to restore your stack, pop everything off the temporary and push back to the original. Stack is intact, and you used only the intended stack interfaces to do it. The bigger issue is that your stack is not an actual structure. Its size is stored in a global, so you can only have one stack. Not very useful.

Comment: @paddy I see, thank you. So my question here is also how can I combine between these codes. Do you have any idea ?!

Comment: Turn your stack into a `struct` that stores the elements _and_ the count (currently `t`). Get that working first, then you can have multiple independent stacks, and it should be pretty obvious what to do from there. If not, I already stated explicitly how to perform the operation.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: Re “An average would generally require the usage of a floating-point accumulator”: Accumulating a sum does not require a type outside the summand type except for overflow considerations. It may be desirable to do the final division with a floating-point type, but that does not require the accumulator to be floating-point.

Comment: Haaland, when code first executes `average += Pop(&stack); }`, what value do you think is in `average` just prior to the addition?

Comment: Stack is totally pointless here, as far as I can tell. Just pop it down, take the total and divide by the number of elements. What am I missing?